# Cutting out parts of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse JSON game result statistic and add/change/delete some values:

```js
bot.Dota2.requestMatchDetails(lobby.match_id);
bot.Dota2.on("matchDetailsData", function (matchId, matchData) {
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matchData));
    data.match.type = "partyStatistic";
    data.match.partyId = bot.currentLobby.id;
    for (i = 0; i < data.match.players.length; i++) {
        delete data.match.players[i].party_id;
        data.match.players[i].account_id = bot.Dota2.ToSteamID(data.match.players[i].account_id + "") + "";
    }
    delete data.vote;
    delete data.result;
    util.log(JSON.stringify('API STATISTIC: ' + JSON.stringify(data)));
}
```

JSON im getting now:

```
{
    "match": {
        "duration": 647,
        "startTime": 1530782586,
        "cluster": 136,
        "first_blood_time": 308,
        "lobby_type": 1,
        "human_players": 2,
        "positive_votes": 0,
        "negative_votes": 0,
        "game_mode": "DOTA_GAMEMODE_1V1MID",
        "radiant_team_score": 2,
        "dire_team_score": 0,
        "match_outcome": "k_EMatchOutcome_RadVictory",
        "pre_game_duration": 90,
        "type": "partyStatistic",
        "partyId": "54333333-0bea-e611-80bc-c8600054b63d"
    }
}
```

JSON i need:

```
{
    "duration": 647,
    "startTime": 1530782586,
    "cluster": 136,
    "first_blood_time": 308,
    "lobby_type": 1,
    "human_players": 2,
    "positive_votes": 0,
    "negative_votes": 0,
    "game_mode": "DOTA_GAMEMODE_1V1MID",
    "radiant_team_score": 2,
    "dire_team_score": 0,
    "match_outcome": "k_EMatchOutcome_RadVictory",
    "pre_game_duration": 90,
    "type": "partyStatistic",
    "partyId": "54333333-0bea-e611-80bc-c8600054b63d"
}
```

I tried to split some symbols at the start and at the end of JSON with:

```
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).substring(9));
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).substring(0, data.length - 1));
```

But im getting errors. Any other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: And the errors are ? Please edit with them

Comment: Try `util.log(JSON.stringify('API STATISTIC: ' + JSON.stringify(data.match)));`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data)["match"]);
```

or if data is already a json-object just

```
JSON.stringify(data["match"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me.